# Admob Campaign not showings ads anymore

Tags: flutter, firebase, admob, google-ads-api

i have a problem with admob campaigns with house ad.

Last week, i implemented ads into my mobile app and it was working. I got a banner ad on my homepage and native ads with custom style into my search page (it's a page for job announces).

I created a campaign with house ad, so custom title, description, body, media ... and it was working.
But since yesterday, the campaign still "active" in AdMob, but there is no more ads from the campaign in my app.

[Last week - Campaign was working, got my custom ad "VivaLaVie"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hGnz.png)

[This week - Campaign not working anymore, got ads for gitlab for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwPoP.png)

I precise it's not just a random ad 1/10 and my custom ad 9/10 times
Now it's always random ads ...

Thanks in advance !

Implementing ads with admob using campaign -> Get my own custom ads.